# HTML Responsive website image center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hey i'm trying to center my images when someone is using an ipad basically below 780px but i am not able to get them to center no matter what i try? My menu and navigation bar are all centered just these images won't

[This is on normal browser PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWGKz.jpg)

[This is the way it looks on tablet but i want to center it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6IhT.png)

My code here

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="news">
        <div>
        <div class="tagline"><h3 class="white">Current News</h3></div>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <div class="box">
            <img src="images/joker.jpg" alt=""/> 
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            <img src="images/joker.jpg" alt=""/> 
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            <img src="images/timber.jpg" alt=""/> 
            </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

CSS here

```
@media screen and (max-width:979px){
    /*Global */
    .container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.box img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .box {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap? Or flexbox? Making use of modern tools will save you the headache of trying to manage positions with CSS

Comment: Simply add `text-align: center;` to your img box style

Comment: @Callat Every time somebody suggest "Use bootstrap!" to solve a simple layout issue this comes to mind ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRBds.jpg and this of course... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/180262

Comment: You can try by ".box img { display: block; }"

Comment: I tried text-align or display block. I tried many ways that's why i ran out of options and came here

Comment: Then you should post your code in fiddle version from where we can get idea, there can be impact from  other code. We don't know what you tried or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:
{

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

}

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue

Comment: Any idea how i would center text 3 boxes again

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexboxes](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your HTML by adding a container around the boxes:

```
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Use flexbox for the container and give the boxes equal space in the screen with the `flex` property:

```
/* Only for demo purposes */

body, html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

/* Main part: flexbox is added to the container box and the flex property allots them equal space with a margin of 10px as well */

.box-container {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
}

.box {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpp7ah8m/7/)

Comment: Any idea how i would center text 3 boxes again

Comment: You can center the text by using flexbox for the each box and setting the 'justify-content' property to 'center' and 'align-items' to 'center' as well